# How to emulate click button in Android for unit testing

Tags: android, unit-testing

How can I emulate clicking a button in my application test. I tried to set focus on the button and send the keypress "Enter" but no cigar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just call the `performClick()` method. See [the View docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#performClick%28%29) for reference.

```
Button button = (Button) findViewByid(R.id.mybutton);
button.performClick();
```

Or, if developing for Ice Cream Sandwich (API Level 15), the [`callOnClick()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#callOnClick%28%29) method was added. `performClick()` is more than suitable for your needs, though.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer didn't quite work for me, the thing I was working with didn't have a `performClick` method. For future people who come here with a situation like mine where you're doing instrumented testing, you might need something like this:

```
onView(withId(R.id.myButton)).perform(ViewActions.click());
```

Comment: Just to mention for clarity, this code is useful if you are using Espresso library

Answer (score 0):

Please look at [Robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/) project. It is a test framework for Android and you can achieve what you desire easily with it, and much more.

Comment: for now I'd prefer to stay within the confines of the standard Android  testing framework

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of problems with the performClick method (relating to using the wrong thread and whatnot).  I had a lot more luck with using TouchUtils.clickView as outlined in this [android training lesson](http://developer.android.com/training/activity-testing/activity-ui-testing.html).  Here is some sample usage:

```
public class ClickFunActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 {
    ...
    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();

        setActivityInitialTouchMode(true);

        mClickFunActivity = getActivity();
        mClickMeButton = (Button) 
                mClickFunActivity.findViewById(R.id.launch_next_activity_button);
    }

    public void testClickMeButton_clickButtonAndExpectInfoText() {
        TouchUtils.clickView(this, mClickMeButton);
        //Do some other testing afterward
    }
}
```

The complete code can be found in the link or [here](http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/AndroidTestingFun.zip).